# Connecting to mySql server using IPv6 in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to mySql instance using IPv6 as Follows:

```
myConnectionString = "server= 2001:3456:2343:1:1436:b2e4:ce65:b987;" + "uid=root;"
+"pwd=passroot;" + "database=mydb;";
try
{
  conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
  conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
  conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
  MySqlConnEstablished = false;
  Exeption = ex;
  IsExceptionRaised = true;
}
```

I keep getting err msg : "Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts"

BUT, when I use the IPv4 address it works fine.

Comment: Is the mysqlserver listening on the ipv6 address?

Comment: the google sql instance supports IPv6 addresses

Comment: does your end support IPv6?

Comment: @mmgross I don't know , how could i figure it out?

Comment: Try to wrap the IP6 into brackets: `[IP6]`, like this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like latest [MySql.Data (8.0.10-rc at the moment)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/8.0.10-rc) still not supported IPv6 at all. I solved the problem by switching to open source [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when MySql Connector is trying to connect to the server using IPv6. You just need to update your "MySql Connector" [driver](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySqlConnector by NuGet  https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/
my demo like this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=::1;uid=ipv6test;pwd=root;database=test1;CharSet=utf8"))
        {
            string sql = "select * from host";
            using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string host = reader["host"] == System.DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["host"].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(host);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```